# Ruby on Rails: One-to-many relationships, but I only want to retrieve just students and 1 homework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, one-to-many

I've 2 objects, Student and Homework. This is a one-to-many relationship where a student can have many Homeworks

I'm trying to use a .find method to retrieve all students and just one homework that he has.

I know I can use Student.find(:all, :include => :homeworks). But, this will return me the student and all it's homeworks.

Comment: This looks more like a many to many relationship. To me a subject could/should have many students too.

Comment: agreed.. think it should be a many to many

Comment: So reformulate your question (and title). The solution should be: Created in a correct way (with `has_many :through` relations), you are able to do: `s = Subject.find(2); s.students` to retrieve all students to one subject.

Comment: I just edited my question. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your relation is one-to-many, you can't pick just one without deciding which one should it be (e.g. first one, if you order them by ids). If so, you can use `#first` method on relation:

```
Student.find(:all, :include => :homeworks).each {|student| student.homeworks.first}
```

If you mean pulling only one subject for each student from database it is more of SQL problem. You would have to write 'ON' clause that would pick single subject on your criterion.

Comment: hi @samuil. i tried `Student.find(:all, :include => :homeworks).each {|student| student.homeworks.first}` there are still Student objects which returns me array of more than 1 homeworks. Is there something i missed or did not understood?

Comment: This solution will pull all data from your db, it is just way to discard all data that you do not use. If you care in this solution about performance, you have to write much more complicated query.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care about performance then your solution is ok. 
Fetch all record and just use the first one in your views or controllers

If you do care about performance (fetching a lot of objects is expensive) then you can add another relation first_homework or latest_homework (adding a new column latest_homework_id in your table's schema) and populate it with the correct id every time a student is assigned a new homework (or a homework is completed or whenever it makes sense for your application logic)

Comment: It is bad idea to add such column, unless it is impossible to determine which homework is latest (by sorting them by id, or created_at). It just makes a bit more complicated query.